# How register Javascripts against a specific view in Plone

Tags: javascript, plone

I'd like to Plone load Javascripts only for a specific view.

I really really want load them in this single view, which is opened rarely and has admin only JS code. I still want Javascript be processed by portal_javascripts, so that caching busting support is automatic.

What this best way to register Javascripts against a specific view and potentially its subclasses? By interface? By full dotted class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Martijn is correct; however, if you really need/want to do it with portal_javascripts, make sure the base class implements an interface, then do something like this for your conditional statement in the portal_javascript registry value.

```
python: context.restrictedTraverse('@@plone_interface_info').provides('my.package.interfaces.IMyInterface')
```

Answer (score 3):

I never bother for such one-off JS resources. Just load your JS directly with the specific view. You can always instruct the few users of that view to CTRL-Reload.

Cluttering up portal_javascript will only make the maintenance burden higher, as you need to make sure you do not break up the mergeability of the global JS resources.

Comment: Exactly right. Very foolish to use portal_javascripts for one view--I've made the mistake before...